# What happens after a collision?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, collision, celestial-mechanics

2 different planets far away from each other, each have an extremely strong water canon. Those 2 canons are aimed to the sky, aimed at each other. They both shoot a massive load of water to each other, targeting each other. The water moves like 2 spheres of water towards each other at a constant speed. Independently the both seem pretty stable while they travel. Then when they hit each other, there is a huge impact, and at first, the 2 spheres explode in tiny drops of water.

What happens next is what interests me. And here is just my take on it.

One possible theory, would be that **the drops just attract each other, move towards each other and stop moving**. - However, I think that is incorrect. The energy which was present at the time of the impact cannot just dissappear.

I do think all drops are in fact attracted to each other. There should be a gravitational point (or multiple gravitational points) and as a drop approaches that point, due to the gravitational force it should accelerate and move through the gravitational point. So, **the drops keep moving back and forth through the center**. That seems to make more sense to me. So, in a way, it's like it's being shaken.

Now, does that mean that they keep moving through each other forever just like that. I don't think that's possible neither, because the more the drops hit each other, it **could result in rotational movement of the drops**. Once they start rotating, there is no need for them to move back and forth to make up for the energy. So, I think at that point the shaking stops, **the drops move closer to each other**.

And as time goes by, more and more of it will be spinning. **The more drops are spinning, and the faster they spin, the smaller the system gets in size**. Now, the system could continue to become smaller and smaller, but only as long as the particles can spin faster, and on a smaller level (more rotational axis).

Finally, as an object spins faster and faster, in becomes harder to accelerate it even more. So, at some point the gravitational pull will not be strong enough to accelerate the spin any further.

Or does all of that result in a kind of radiation perhaps which lets the energy escape?

To what extend is the above reasoning correct?
(I am clearly not a physicist)

Comment: You are right that energy cannot just disappear, but a significant portion can be dissipated as heat.

Comment: Watching a video of a sped up galactic merger is a great way to see a similar scenario, though it's obviously not as dense as water is, the visualization of how messy such a collision can be is neat.

Comment: @Triactticus thanks for the hint. Beautiful videos indeed.

Comment: @DanDan0101 On that note, I always find it difficult to predict to which shape energy would chose to transform (i.e. heat vs mechanical). I guess it just always takes the easiest way out, right ? - So if it has trouble moving/bending/rotating, it creates some heat ?

Comment: @bvdb I guess that is because heat as a form of energy has more entropy